# Unhide NSwindow hidden by setHidesOnDeactivate?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow

Im pretty sure the answer must be quite easy, but for some reason I can't get it to work!

I have a window, and this code:

```
[someWindow setHidesOnDeactivate:YES];
```

I have a status item, and the following code

```
- (void)openWindow{
   if ([someWindow isVisible]) {
         NSLog(@"CLOSING");
         [lyricWindow close];
   }else {
          [someWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
         NSLog(@"SHOWING");
   }

}
```

This worked when I closed the window and wanted to open it again. Now that I've implemented the hides of deactivate I am lost as to what I need to do! I've tried all sorts of things... I want the window to show again and the window to become active when I click the status item! I think thats my problem.

How can I make the window active when I click on a status item?

I get the following in the log:

> CLOSING SHOWING CLOSING SHOWING

Closing is first regardless if the window is hidden or not, which is rather intriguing, because id guess `isVisible` would return `false` if the window has been hidden. Anyhow, I get no window. How can I unhide the window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same problem where I couldn't get a window to re-show after it was hidden from deactivation.  In my case, I was showing a NSPanel (subclass of NSWindow) when a NSStatusItem was pressed.

The following code finally got my NSPanel to re-show up:

```
[NSApp arrangeInFront:sender];
[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

I'm pretty sure 'activateIgnoringOtherApps' is the key here.  For me, it's not ideal because it takes focus away from the user's current application.

Comment: `[NSApp unhide];` seems the key thing called by `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];`, so you can safetly replace it.

Comment: For this answer, would `[NSApp unhideWithoutActivation]` be more appropriate?